# Создать базу данных MySQL java

Tags: java, mysql

Нужно сделать БД содержащую массив чисел (х,у координаты) и извлекать числа в ява классе. Как создать саму БД в MySQL? поменять расширение текстового документа? или в Eclipse IDE есть что-то? На сайте MySQL не очен понял где искать

```
    public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception{
    try {
        String driver= "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String url= "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/engine";//mysql database; localhost = ur computer, IP address = server; name of database
        String user= "phill"; //user name. idk if it's necessary
        String password= "mypass"; //user password. idk if it's necessary
        Class.forName(driver);
        Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

        System.out.println("connected");
        return con;
    } catch (Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}
    return null;
}
```

Comment: БД должна храниться на локальном компьютере "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/engine" и называться engine. Обязательны ли username и password?

Comment: Есть такая штука как JDBC, с помощью её можно подключиться к БД. И отправлять запросы.

Comment: Как пользоваться?

Comment: Пример кода? ....

Comment: Здесь есть урок
http://www.javenue.info/post/java-jdbc-api

Comment: хочу заметить что вам нужно скачать данную либу и подключить к своему проекту

Comment: Как это сделать? Я новичок в БД. Вернее, умею работать но в Microsoft Acces SQL

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Comment: Мы создаем БД отдельно или в ява классе?

Comment: Уже скачал, установил и добавил jar  в проект

Comment: БД создается в БД, причем тут Java Class? Если вы хотите наложить  таблицу на Java Class, то вам нужен Hibernet

Comment: Можно таблицу SQL из Microsoft acces использовать как БД для java класса? или MySQL != SQL

Comment: Если вы новичок, то можно использовать MySQL Workbanch и делать все через интерфейс, в целом вам нужно почитать про JDBC, для работы с БД.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ на собственный вопрос. Если кому то пригодиться, то почитать можно подробно на http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/javadb-141163.html#creating

Comment: Стоит написать главное непосредственно в ответе.